# Ruby twitter gem. how to get people who favorite my posts

Tags: ruby, twitter, rubygems, posts, favorite

Im trying to make an app which would iterate through my own posts and get a list of users who favorited a post. Afterwards I would like the application to follow each of those users if I am not already following them. I am using Ruby for this.

This is my code now:

```
@client = Twitter::REST::Client.new(config)
OpenSSL::SSL::VERIFY_PEER = OpenSSL::SSL::VERIFY_NONE
user = @client.user()
tweets = @client.user_timeline(user).take(20)
num_of_tweets = tweets.length
puts "tweets found: #{tweets.length}"
tweets.each do |item|
    puts "#{ item}" #iterating through my posts here
end
```

any suggestions?

Answer (score 1):

That information isn't exposed in the Twitter API, either through a timeline collection or via [the endpoint representing a single tweet](https://dev.twitter.com/rest/reference/get/statuses/show/%3Aid). This'll be why the twitter gem, which provides a useable interface around the Rest API, cannot give you what you're after.

Third party sites such as [Favstar](http://favstar.fm) do display that information, but as far as I know their own API does not expose the relevant users in any manageable way.